# install gtkmm-4.0 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

Why can't I do this with

```
sudo apt install libgtkmm-4.0-dev
```

It appears to be available in pkgs.org. I know I can install libgtkmm-3.0-dev using the above so why not 4.0?

Comment: gtkmm-4.0 is "a future version", so far available in Arch Linux, Mageia Cauldron, OpenSuSE Tumbleweed .

Comment: And it depends on GTK 4 which not packaged even in Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Ubuntu release has a fixed set of software available in the repositories. Only one version is available - except web browsers and other critical components - and that version was decided some time before the actual release.

According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtkmm the `gtkmm` version available for Ubuntu 20.04 is **3.24.0-1**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read the download instructions at developer.gnome.org but I'm unsure about the dependencies. Is it possible to install 4.0 on ubuntu 20.04 or does what you're saying above mean I would have to wait for a new version of ubuntu to use 4.0? I've not used gtkmm before but I thought if I was going to learn it I might as well start with the latest version.

Comment: @NoComprende If you really need the latest version for development, run a rolling release distro in a VM, and use it there.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Thanks but that's a bit over my head. I've only been using linux a few months.

Comment: @NoComprende Ubuntu uses a fixed set of packages for stability, and you need to upgrade the version of Ubuntu to get new versions of a software. But there are operating systems, which always have the latest software in the repositories (they are called rolling release operating systems, e.g. Arch (not very beginner friendly), Manjaro (beginner friendly), etc). I suggested you set up one of those operating systems in virtualbox (search how to in your favorite search engine), and there you can install gtkmm-4.0, in case you need it for software development.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Took your advice shortly after this thread, installed manjaro and haven't looked back since. It's great to be able to issue a single command and have everything updated.